# Returning the passed slot with an extra class from vuejs render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a component who task is to simply add a class on whatever element is passed to it as slot when its just one node

Usage:

```
<my-component>
 <button>hello</button>
</my-component>
```

Output:

```
<button class="added-by-component">hello</button>
```

I tried with `<template>` tag, but `<slot>` isn't allowed to be on the root.

Even with `render()` function, I tried returning the passed slot's vnode after modifying the `class` property:

```
render (createElement) {
 var vnode = this.$slots.default[0]
 vnode.data = vnode.data || {}
 vnode.data.class = { 'added-by-component': this.someCondition }
 return vnode
}
```

Even this doesn't work as expected. I don't get the class added even when the condition is true.

Comment: Utilization the render method is the only way to achieve desired functionality. But you are using it naïve - intuitive way. Dive into the render method documentation and study over how to use it properly. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const Wrapper = {
  functional: true,
  render (h, ctx) {
    const slots = ctx.slots()
    const node = slots.default[0]

    node.data.staticClass = [
      'my-class',
      node.data.staticClass || ''
    ].join(' ')

    return node
  }
}
```

You can use `data.class` too but it would need extra type handling.